# playing Youtube videos in fancy box

Tags: video, youtube, fancybox

Good day

I created script at the following URL: http://www.radiocraft.ca

at lines 634 to 668

I did something wrong and as the result when I am clinking on the play button, instead of opening fancybox, I am sent to a full screen version of the Youtube video. What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Also, how to make the corners of the fancybox video round with radius of 5 pt?

Thank you again.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of code here.

Answer (score 0):

you don't  have `video` method, i think you want to use `fancybox` instead

like this :

```
$("#yt").click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'padding'        : 0,
                        'autoScale'      : false,
                        'transitionIn'   : 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut'  : 'elastic',
                        'title'          : this.title,
                        'speedIn'        : 600, 
                        'speedOut'       : 200, 
                        'width'          : 680,
                        'height'         : 495,
                        'href'           : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                        'type'           : 'swf',
                        'swf'            : {
                            'wmode'              : 'transparent',
                            'allowfullscreen'    : 'true'
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: Alex,Thank you. I uploaded code your provided. it is still opening in a full screen Youtube video instead of Fancybox window. Something is still amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Just add into yours code this lines of code: (this is javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".video").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

and to your html link (where you have class video add next class **fancybox.iframe**)

So your html link looks like: (including your href image)

```
<a class="video fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/meqnw_DdArE?fs=1&autoplay=1"><img alt="Corvette Video" src="Headphone%20Amplifier%20Corvette%20Video%20Main.jpg" width="587" height="391" class="style40" /></a>
```

I hope this mini-fancybox tutorial will help you ;)

Comment: I cannot post code - the site does not allow me to post it in the comment section and I cannot post in answer my own question. The URL and the code lines are mentioned in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Lukas. I replaced the relevant part of code with yours. It still opens in a full screen Youtube video instead of Fancybox.

Comment: You just have this at the link: `fancybox.iframe` instead of: `video fancybox.iframe`.. Check it and fix it.. ;) I look at your code and you have javascript which I post to you wrapped by some `$("#yt").click(function() {` remove this part of your code..

Comment: I did that and it still opens in a full screen Youtube video.

Comment: And if I can recommendedto you, clear your code.. You have body tag at the middle of main body.. Try to use html validator and please, do not use FrontPage.. Try to learn a few tags with which you can built custom page ;)

Comment: At javascript, remove last line of code -> **)};**  is making maybe problems AND to HTML LINK add that "video" class

Comment: Nice ;) but you still have `<a class="fancybox.iframe"...` instead of `<a class="video fancybox.iframe"...`

Comment: Last line, you have to add is: `});` to javascript.. But do not change any else line of code.. ;)

Comment: Lukas, above you said to remove )}; Anyways, I added second )}; and it still does not work.

Comment: If it doesnt work, try to swap HTML and JAVASCRIPT - So first in code must be Javascript declared and after that HTML... Sorry mate but read your code is so difficult.. and swap brackets, it must be `});` instead of `)};`

Comment: Thank you Lukas, but this stub in a dark approach does not work.